# How can I create a slider with a smooth autoplay loop

Tags: javascript, slider, frontend, slide, autoplay

I would like to create a slider like the one here" https://www.revolut.com/en-CZ , I'm working in Javascript

How can I make it so that the slider runs in a continuous loop, on autoplay, with a smooth transition?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This Site is not meant to give you tutorials or things like that. If you want to achieve something you have seen on a Website and want to implement into your own the right approach for this Site is to just try it out yourself. Once you get stuck you can ask a Question for example " i tried this and got stuck, this is what i want to achieve and this is what i have tried", add your Code and then we can help you out by pointing you in the right direction. Check out This for further explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by the CSS property - "animation", with no need for Javascript added to that.
Here is some JSfiddle example :

https://jsfiddle.net/7p4j2a3u/1/
code example

```
  animation: moveSlideshow 12s linear infinite;
```

Heres also more detailed explenation about "animation" from Css Tricks

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/